# (MongoDB) Data submitted from user A is being sent into User B's document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1deiM.jpg

I'm finding and updating the current user's document in the db using:
Player.findOneAndUpdate(
player.discordID (example below), but it ignores the discordID query and inputs the data into the wrong document. I logged the currrent user's discordID in the terminal to make sure it is fetching the current user's and it is.

```
if (
                              // if user submitted data matches the gamertags and platforms listed in-
                              // their call of duty account, execute assignRoleNow
                              (loggedIn =
                                true &&
                                checkTag == true &&
                                checkPlat == true)
                            ) {
                              console.log(player.discordID);
                              console.log(player);
                              Player.findOneAndUpdate(
                                player.discordID,
                                {
                                  $set: {
                                    platform: platform,
                                    gamertag: gamertag,
                                  },
                                },
                                function callback(err, doc) {
                                  if (err) {
                                    // Show errors
                                    console.log(err);
                                  }
                                }
                              );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query portion of you findOneAndUpdate may not be in the correct format. Remember, it should look the same as a find for the Player so it may need to be:

```
{discordId: player.discordID}
```

instead of just:

```
player.discordID
```

Comment: I ended up resolving the issue! I updated the format to what you pointed out and that also made me look at all of the findOneAndUpdate's to make sure discordID was being targeted correctly. Ended up that one was returning undefined, once i fixed that up it worked. Thank you for the push in the right direction!